# Ember: use this.get() in a validation function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, this

I have a date validator for an input field:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
moment: Ember.inject.service(),
dateValidation: [{
    message: 'invalid date',
    validate: function(inputDate) {
      if (!inputDate) {
        return true; //allow empty date
      }
      return this.get('moment').moment(inputDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();
    }
  }],
});
```

I use ember-moment to validate the date. Usually I use `this.get('moment').moment(...)` but in the function `this.get()` is not defined (the `get()` function is not defined, because `this` refers to the validator function, not to the ember component, which have got a `get()` function).
I know that `this` refers to the function instead of my component, but how can I fix it? Using `Ember.get()` didn't work for me.

I am using ember-paper and the paper-input has got a customValidations-attribute which has to be an array (dateValidation in my case)

e.g:

```
{{paper-input
   type="date"
   value=atDate
   onChange=(action (mut atDate))
   customValidations=dateValidation}}
```

Comment: Hi Ben. `this.get` is undefined, or `this.get('moment')` is undefined?

Comment: @vothaison this.get(), also updated question

Comment: I think the problem is in the code that uses dateValidation. If you have control over that code, you can past `this` (component instance) into each `validate()` call.

Answer (score 0):

1. First option like @vothaison mentioned in comments, you can pass `this` reference to validation method.
2. You can inject `moment` inside your object definition.

   ```
   export default Ember.Component.extend({
   moment: Ember.inject.service(),
   dateValidation: [],
   init() {
       this._super(...arguments);
       var objectValidation = {
           message: 'invalid date',
           myMoment: this.get('moment'),
           validate: function(inputDate) {
               if (!inputDate) {
                   return true; //allow empty date
               }
               return this.get('myMoment').moment(inputDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();
           }
       };
       this.get('dateValidation').pushObject(objectValidation);
   }
   ```

   });

Comment: @vothaison & kumkanillam: I cant pass a reference of this to the function because it will be called from the template every time the value(date) from input field changes.

Comment: your way is working, but in my opinion it is a bit bad coding. Just having the dateValidation array without using init() would be better

Comment: You can pass `this` reference from template just like passing arguments to action in template. why this structure `dateValidation: [{}]` is required ?

Comment: it is required by ember-paper. I updated the question

Comment: Acutally in my app, I am using `moment` without importing and injecting as service ?. can you try it directly by removing injecting service? ie., `moment(inputDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()`

Comment: I know that this will work but it will cause to use the global moment object and in ember-cli there will be a js hint saying moment isnt defined. Also see the readme on github https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment

Comment: the function would be working, but there is a jshint error, saying 'moment is not defined'.

Comment: you can ignore jshint error for moment. if you dont want this to be listed then you can add `"moment":true` to `.jshintrc` file located in root of application directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test this, but a simple `bind` looks like it should fix the problem:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
moment: Ember.inject.service(),
dateValidation: [{
    message: 'invalid date',
    validate: function(inputDate) {
      if (!inputDate) {
        return true; //allow empty date
      }
      return this.get('moment').moment(inputDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();
    }.bind(this)
  }],
});
```

Comment: sorry, this isnt working. Same error: 'TypeError: this.get is not a function(…)'

Comment: Is there any chance you can get an Ember Twiddle of the code posted so we can have dig into the code?